# C# FileSystemWatcher firing when i physically drop a file, however not when i use File.Move

Tags: c#, events, filesystemwatcher

Excel files are dropped manually into a local folder, there is a FileWatcher which converts the file into a new filestructure and moves it to the next folder which also have a filewatcher. The problem is that when this file is moved to the next folder the filewatcher does not fire any event. However if i cut it and drop it physically the event fires. 
I am using File.Move to copy file from folder1 to folder2

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: What do you mean by "new filestructure"? Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468637/filesystemwatcher-not-raising-when-files-are-copied-or-moved-to-folder

Answer (score 2):

you should look at [FileSystemWatcher detect when file is moved to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877225/filesystemwatcher-detect-when-file-is-moved-to-folder)

Actually when there is a move, the filesystemwatcher send a delete (in the source directory watcher) and a create (in the target directory watcher).

Answer (score 0):

try to use renamed event.

Another reason could be the buffer size may exceeded.

```
 Public void WatchItBaby()
 {
    // ...
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"c:\temp\", "*.txt");            
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChangedOrRenamed);          
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnChangedOrRenamed);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    // ...
 }

 private void OnChangedOrRenamed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
 {
    // stuff        
 }
```